# Flutter Scroll multiple ListViews together without the separators between them

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I am trying to build a vertical ListView of with horizontal ListViews.
My problem is, that I want to scroll all the Rows together without scrolling the separators between the Rows. That is why I can't just use a SingleChildScrollView around all of this.
I know Flutter does not allow to use one ScrollConroller for multiple Widgets.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

This is a simplified code example of my problem:

```
class ListViewTest extends StatelessWidget{

   final ScrollController _horizontalScrollController = ScrollController(); 
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: 20,
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => const Divider(
        thickness: 1,
        color: Colors.black,
        height: 41,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        child: ListView.separated(
          //controller: _horizontalScrollController, does not work
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 10,
          separatorBuilder: (context, j) => SizedBox(width: 5,),
          itemBuilder: (context, j) =>  Container(
            height: 40,
            width: 60,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text(
              "cell $i - $j"
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:

[image]
See it as a Table with a Divider for each Row.
Currently I can scroll the entire table vertically. But horizontally I can only scroll one Row at once.
What I want is to scroll one Row and all other Rows to follow, so that all Columns are aligned. But the Dividers should not move horizontally.

Comment: can you provide image you wanted to achieve>?

Comment: Do you mean like this?

Comment: Does `column-divider` are also scrollable or on fixed position?

Comment: As said, the divider is static and should not move horizontally.

Comment: You mean you can scroll horizontally on cell and also can scroll verticaly for whole page?

Comment: Yes, scroll the wohle Page vertically, and the green cells without the dividers horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with adding an extra package to solve your problem, there's an excellent solution from **google.dev** team that does just what you need: [linked_scroll_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/linked_scroll_controller)

An implementation based on your example would be rather trivial:

```
class ListViewTest extends StatelessWidget{

   final _controllerGroup = LinkedScrollControllerGroup(); 
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: 20,
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => const 
        Container(
        child: Text('Column-Divider'),
        height: 41,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        child: ListView.separated(
          key: Key('$i'),
          controller: _controllerGroup.addAndGet(), // << add here
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 10,
          separatorBuilder: (context, j) => SizedBox(width: 5,),
          itemBuilder: (context, j) =>  Container(
            height: 40,
            width: 60,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text(
              "cell $i - $j"
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind the note from the package:

> If you add controllers dynamically, the corresponding scrollables must
> be given unique keys to avoid the scroll offset going out of sync.

Comment: this looks promising, thanks
I'll test it

Comment: np, you're welcome. good luck!

Comment: It seems to work, but I get this Error when scrolling:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/overscroll_indicator.dart': Failed assertion: line 243 pos 14: 'notification.metrics.axis == widget.axis': is not true.

Comment: Never mind, it seems not be be a problem of this package.
It works, thank you.

Comment: Hi @Haissem55 , I get the same error when scrolling.

'package:flutter/src/widgets/overscroll_indicator.dart': Failed assertion: line 243 pos 14: 'notification.metrics.axis == widget.axis': is not true.

How did you fix this and what was the issue?

Comment: The Problem was a statefull widget, that rebuild the controllers. So I moved them up, to where I build the Table an wrapped each of them in a container together with an uniq key. gvive that uniq key to the table row item builder. That did it for me.